# Enable Bluetooth capability in class library

Tags: c#, bluetooth-lowenergy, uwp, windows-10-universal, class-library

I am developing a uwp that can detect ble. The `BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher.Received` event works perfectly in my app. I was trying to transfer the codes that related to bluetooth, but I don't know how to enable bluetooth capability as done in `appmanifest`. How to enable the capability in class library.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using visual studio right click on your project file and click properties. Then under "Package manifest" navigate to the capabilities section and check Bluetooth under Capabilities:

Otherwise you can open your package.appxmanifest directly and add this line DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth"   under your Capabilities section

Comment: The answer is for UWP, not for class library.. Sorry!!